# Unable to filter out 0s

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I'm trying to filter out any rows that are 0 in field 55 in the below code but it looks to be filtering all rows out even though there's rows with values greater or smaller than 0 in field 55. Any assistance would be great.

```
Range("A9:BF9").AutoFilter field:=55, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<0"
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

As is, your filter is looking for values that are *both greater than and less than 0* - no value can satisfy those criteria.

Simplify this to: `Range("A9:BF9").AutoFilter field:=55, Criteria1:="<>0"` - where you filter for any values not equal to 0.

Or if you prefer the roundabout way, change your operator to `xlOr` from `xlAnd`.